# dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedTheme>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _DetailsState.initState() completed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am doing animated Appbar and I want to determine color of AppBar on theme of application but when I did this I received this error:

`dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedTheme>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _DetailsState.initState() completed`

here is my initState code, I tried here to determine color depending on theme of application:

```
  late AnimationController _ColorAnimationController;
  late AnimationController _TextAnimationController;
  late Animation _colorTween, _iconColorTween, _bgLeadingColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _ColorAnimationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 0));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? Colors.black : Colors.white)
        .animate(_ColorAnimationController);
    _iconColorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.grey, end: Colors.white)
        .animate(_ColorAnimationController);
    _bgLeadingColor = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black26, end: Colors.transparent)
        .animate(_ColorAnimationController);


    _TextAnimationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 0));

    super.initState();
  }
```

and

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = widget.size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.axis == Axis.vertical) {
            _ColorAnimationController.animateTo(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels / 350);

            _TextAnimationController.animateTo(
              (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels - 350) / 50);
            return true;
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        height: size.height * 0.49,
                        child: PhotoViewer(
                            /*
                            */
                        )
                    ),
                    SquareBoxMovableBuilder(
                      /*
                      */
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: size.height * 0.075,
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _ColorAnimationController,
                  builder: (context, child) => AppBar(
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: _bgLeadingColor.value,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(size.width * 0.02),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: size.height * 0.01,
                            left: size.height * 0.01,
                            right: size.height * 0.01,
                            bottom: size.height * 0.01,
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: _colorTween.value,
                    elevation: 0,
                    titleSpacing: 0.0,
                    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                      color: _iconColorTween.value,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

My question is how to avoid this error and still determine color of appbar depending on theme of application?

Comment: You call `Theme.of(context).brightness` inside state.init() and before super.initState(). That's where the error comes from

Comment: do it inside [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) method, for more read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Comment: @JoRa calling it after `super.initState()` will not fix it - you cannot simply call `Theme.of` inside `initState`